# How to sort records in grid view on click of header of a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I wanted to sort a grid view by column when user clicks on a column header. Here user can click any column and grid view is sorted based on the column clicked.  This is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployeeStatus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" AllowSorting="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvEmployeeStatus_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gvEmployeeStatus_Sorting" >

 protected void gvEmployeeStatus_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        loginName = (String)(Session["LoginName"]);
        dsLoginDetail = clsBLogic.TblLogin(loginName);                
        tblEmployeeNo = dsLoginDetail.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeNo"].ToString();
        BindDataTogvEmployeeStatus(tblEmployeeNo);

        DataTable dataTable =    gvEmployeeStatus.DataSource as DataTable;
        if(dataTable != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);
            gvEmployeeStatus.DataSource = dataView;
            gvEmployeeStatus.DataBind();
        }

    }

    private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
         string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                break;

            case SortDirection.Descending:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

Record in grid view comes from data set. Now when i run the code, nothing happens. I had set break point on gvEmployeeStatus_Sorting event to check when will it be fired. It it is not being fired. How can i sort records!!

Answer (score 0):

As u mentioned *sorting* is not triggered, I guess you are missing the attribute `SortExpression` in `<asp:TemplateField> or <asp:BoundField>`

For Example,

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Header 1" SortExpression="ColumName1">
```

or

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Your Header 1" HeaderText="Your Header 1" SortExpression="ColumName1" />
```

Comment: i have included sortexpression.. header text is underlined and page is postback but records are not sorted.

Comment: @AgustusCodes : May i know, the control enters into `gvEmployeeStatus_Sorting()` function?

Comment: i was skeptical here.. for testing this, i had placed break point in this function but break point did not enter here??

Answer (score 0):

On aspx page set this property to the gridview.

`onsortcommand="ComponentGridView_Sorting`.

Then place this in the back-end of aspx.cs page.

```
protected void Datagrid1_SortCommand(object source, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string strSQL;
    DataTable dt;
    strSQL = "(SQL SELECT STATEMENT HERE)";
    dt = strSQL;
        {
            string SortDir = string.Empty;
            if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                dir = SortDirection.Descending;
                SortDir = "Desc";
            }
            else
            {
                dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
                SortDir = "Asc";
            }
            DataView sortedView = new DataView(dt);
            sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDir;
            Datagrid1.DataSource = sortedView;
            Datagrid1.DataBind();
        }
}
protected SortDirection dir
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["dirState"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#region For Grid view Header Sorting..!!
    public SortDirection dir
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void grdAdd_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortingDirection = string.Empty;
        if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            dir = SortDirection.Descending;
            sortingDirection = "Desc";
        }
        else
        {
            dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
            sortingDirection = "Asc";
        }
        DataTable dtgrd = AdditionBL.BindAdditionMaster();/**Data Table Bind For Short View**/
        DataView sortedView = new DataView(dtgrd);
        sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
        grdAddition.DataSource = sortedView;
        grdAddition.DataBind();
    }
    #endregion
```